# Is non semi-positive definite matrix invertible?

Tags: matrices, inverse, covariance, positive-definite

I'm aware that positive definite matrix is invertible. I've also read that a matrix is semi-positive definite if and only if the matrix is invertible.

Then, is my matrix invertible when it is not positive definite, nor not semi-positive definite?

One more question - I've encountered a situation in which I have non-positive definite matrix due to floating point precision issues: some of my elements were $-1.623$e-16.

I am computing a covariance matrix, so I know that my matrix should theoretically be semi-positive definite. Therefore, $-1.623$e-16 is negative due to rounding errors. In a situation like this, is it safe to replace it with $0$?

Thanks,

Comment: You "also read" where? There are plenty of invertible matrices which are not semi-positive definite. And plenty of semi-positive definite which are not invertible.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is a mathematical question (and not a computing one), then yes a non positive semidefinite matrix can be invertible.

For example, if a $n\times n$ real matrix has $n$ eigenvalues and none of which is zero, then this matrix is invertible. If these eigenvalues are all negative, then the matrix is negative definite and so, in particular, **not** positive semidefinite. And if some eigenvalues are positive and the remaining eigenvalues are negative, then the matrix is neither positive definite nor negative definite nor positive semidefinite nor negative semidefinite; *nonetheless*, the matrix is still invertible.

Comment: Don't we require the $n \times n$ matrix to also be symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not try and make too many connections between positive definiteness and invertibility. For instance, 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

is an SPD matrix that is not invertible.

Some sources:

1. https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/diagonalization.html
2. http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/417/SpectralTheorem.pdf (in particular, read how qualified and limited the statement is)